# How to check if a Go program isn't running via the go run command?

Tags: go

I want to know if there is a non OS-specific way to test if a Go program is launched by using the `go run` command or by executing the binary produced by the `go build` command.

Comment: "or directly from the source without compiling" this cannot be done. `go run` _does_ compile the program.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First: it's **always compiled**.

Second: **There is no guaranteed way** to tell the difference between binaries compiled using `go build` and `go run`.

`go run main.go` just builds a temporary binary and executes it.

You can look at the path of the binary being executed by printing `os.Args[0]` (the first argument). eg for the following program:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(os.Args[0])
}
```

```
$ go run main.go
/tmp/go-build854217312/b001/exe/main

$  go build -o main . && ./main
./main
```

You could try to detect the fact that the first one is in a temporary directory but the location will depend on the OS and is not guaranteed to remain the same across go versions.

Overall, it might not be worth it. `go run` is not acceptable for any serious binary, it should always be compiled.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the function I use to get the working directory, whether I run with `go run` or whether I build it:

```golang
func GetWorkDir() string {
    ex, err := os.Executable()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    dir := filepath.Dir(ex)

    // Helpful when developing:
    // when running `go run`, the executable is in a temporary directory.
    if strings.Contains(dir, "go-build") {
        return "."
    }
    return filepath.Dir(ex)
}
```